# Convert horizontal table to vertical in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following table format:

[image]

I need to convert this table to following format:

[image]

I looked for PIVOT function in other questions, but the "Key" values in input table is not a fixed set of values, they can be anything. I also looked for other such questions but I am not sure in my case, how the query should be written.

MY code is :

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
ORDER BY RouteCode) AS SrNo
, RouteCode AS X
, SUM(Units) AS Y
FROM
    [ INTERFACE_ok ] .[ dbo ] .[ v_A40OrdersBhQt ]
WHERE [ DeliveryDate ] > CAST(
        FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE () AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME
    )
    AND CustomerCode LIKE '900%'
GROUP BY [ RouteCode ]
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What's your dbms? mysql or sqlserver or others?

Comment: My dbms is Sqlserver

Comment: Ok I have answered your question, there is a sqlserver solution. @Leace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for *Dynamics pivot*.

The main steps are as follows

1. Declare variables `@sqlX` and `@sqlY` to carry your `MAX` function and `CASW WHEN` Expression to create `X` and `Y` pivot colnums.
2. use `CONCAT` to combine your SUM function and CASW WHEN Expression string and main select string and `UNION ALL`  `@sqlX` and `@sqlY` query string.
3. use `EXECUTE` function execute SQL Dynamically.

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  SrNo INT,
  X  VARCHAR(100),
  Y INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'N1',100);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,'N2',200);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3,'N3',300);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,'N4',400);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (5,'N5',500);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (6,'N6',600);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (7,'N7',700);
```

Here is mysql sample.

```
SET @sqlX = NULL;
SET @sqlY = NULL;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN SrNo =',
      SrNo,
      ' THEN X END) '
    )
  ) INTO @sqlX
FROM T;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN SrNo =',
      SrNo,
      ' THEN Y END) '
    )
  ) INTO @sqlY
FROM T;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ''X'', ', @sqlX, ' 
                   FROM T
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT ''Y'', ', @sqlY, '
                   FROM T
                   ');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Mysql sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6ZT1viPNNYE4qP8p7m7pmQ/0)

**SQL-Server version**

```
DECLARE @sqlX VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlY VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sqlX = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', CAST( MAX(CASE WHEN SrNo =' + CAST(SrNo AS VARCHAR(5)) +  ' THEN X END) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) '
            FROM T
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @sqlY = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',CAST( MAX(CASE WHEN SrNo = ' + CAST(SrNo AS VARCHAR(5)) +  ' THEN Y END) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) '
            FROM T
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

set @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ''X'', ', @sqlX, ' 
                   FROM T
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT ''Y'', ', @sqlY, '
                   FROM T');

execute(@sql)
```

[sqlserver sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b53e727ce095401cae63827f6ec1c354)

**RESULT**

```
    | X | MAX(CASE WHEN SrNo =1 THEN X END) | MAX(CASE WHEN SrNo =2 THEN X END) | MAX(CASE WHEN SrNo =3 THEN X END) | MAX(CASE WHEN SrNo =4 THEN X END) | MAX(CASE WHEN SrNo =5 THEN X END) | MAX(CASE WHEN SrNo =6 THEN X END) | MAX(CASE WHEN SrNo =7 THEN X END) |
    |---|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|
    | X |                                N1 |                                N2 |                                N3 |                                N4 |                                N5 |                                N6 |                                N7 |
    | Y |                               100 |                               200 |                               300 |                               400 |                               500 |                               600 |                               700 |
```

**Note**: 
`T` can instead of your subquery or current result set.

Answer (score 1):

Aaron Bertrand wrote up an article that should fit your need:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
(
  ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name      NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
  /* other columns */
);
INSERT dbo.Products VALUES
(1, N'foo'),
(2, N'bar'),
(3, N'kin');
CREATE TABLE dbo.OrderDetails
(
  OrderID INT,
  ProductID INT NOT NULL
    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Products(ProductID),
  Quantity INT
  /* other columns */
);
INSERT dbo.OrderDetails VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(1, 2, 2),
(2, 1, 1),
(3, 3, 1);
```

And his Dynamic solution was to apply a stuff to the PIVOT statement:

Write a sub-query that collects the columns:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(Name)
  FROM (SELECT p.Name FROM dbo.Products AS p
  INNER JOIN dbo.OrderDetails AS o
  ON p.ProductID = o.ProductID
  GROUP BY p.Name) AS x;
```

Then create your executable SQL:

```
SET @sql = N'
SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT p.Name, o.Quantity
   FROM dbo.Products AS p
   INNER JOIN dbo.OrderDetails AS o
   ON p.ProductID = o.ProductID
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Quantity) FOR Name IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
```

And finally, run it:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```